# Visual Studio Shortcut to Auto-Add Event Delegate Methods

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, delegates, shortcut, addhandler

In C# adding event handler methods is very easy. You just type "object.event +=" and then press tab twice.

Is there anything like this for VB projects?

*Note: This is for dynamically created controls or controls that are not declared WithEvents.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the object and the event in the top of the coding window and VB will automatically create the method for handling the event and hooking it up in the designer file. Besides from this there is no such feature available not with Visual Studio nor Resharper.

The C# development team added support for this, but for some reason the VB guys haven't gotten around to it yet, nor has I seen any third party addons doing anything like it.